# Total distance calculation from LatLng List

Tags: dart, gps, flutter

Im using dart/flutter and the `'package:latlong/latlong.dart'` to parse a GPX file into a list of LatLng objects. That is working fine, but the next step is to find the total distance of the route.

The question here is

> how can I get the total distance from a list of LatLng objects in
>   Dart?

I have used Haversine formula before in Java, but not sure the best way to implement it using Dart. Any help of suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

Below is an attempt to get total distance based on the answer below. For some reason though it doesn't add to `totalDistance` and doesn't return a double.

The below is suppose to iterate through a list of 60+ LatLng objects and find distance between each one, adding to a totalDistance double which is returned at the end of the loop.

```
 static double getDistanceFromGPSPointsInRoute(List<LatLng> gpsList) {
    double totalDistance = 0.0;

    for (var i = 0; i < gpsList.length; i++) {
      var p = 0.017453292519943295;
      var c = cos;
      var a = 0.5 -
          c((gpsList[i + 1].latitude - gpsList[i].latitude) * p) / 2 +
          c(gpsList[i].latitude * p) *
              c(gpsList[i + 1].latitude * p) *
              (1 - c((gpsList[i + 1].longitude - gpsList[i].longitude) * p)) /
              2;
      double distance = 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
      totalDistance += distance;
      print('Distance is ${12742 * asin(sqrt(a))}');
    }
    print('Total distance is $totalDistance');
    return totalDistance;
  }
```

**Output**

```
flutter: Distance is 0.004143962775784678
flutter: Distance is 0.0041439635323316775
flutter: Distance is 0.007796918986828574
flutter: Distance is 0.007285385943437824
flutter: Distance is 0.006890844300938902
flutter: Distance is 0.006353952460010352
flutter: Distance is 0.005560051252981138
```

As you can see above, there is no mention of Total Distance.

**Example of LatLng List**

```
flutter: -36.84975 , 174.646685
flutter: -36.849692 , 174.646497
flutter: -36.84967 , 174.646436
flutter: -36.849578 , 174.646264
flutter: -36.849502 , 174.646164
flutter: -36.849367 , 174.646038
flutter: -36.849209 , 174.645959
flutter: -36.849155 , 174.64594
flutter: -36.849107 , 174.645932
flutter: -36.849058 , 174.645922
flutter: -36.848952 , 174.645895
flutter: -36.84886 , 174.645906
flutter: -36.84879 , 174.645913
flutter: -36.848748 , 174.645836
flutter: -36.848744 , 174.645802
```

Comment: Can you share your lat long list ?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try this please. I tested it with Google Maps and works accurately. You can do a loop and find total distance in KM by using 2 points each time. *I added some random dummy data to show how it works.* Copy this code to https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ and test easily.

```
import 'dart:math' show cos, sqrt, asin;

void main() {
  double calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2){
    var p = 0.017453292519943295;
    var c = cos;
    var a = 0.5 - c((lat2 - lat1) * p)/2 + 
          c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) * 
          (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p))/2;
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
  }
  
  List<dynamic> data = [
    {
      "lat": 44.968046,
      "lng": -94.420307
    },{
      "lat": 44.33328,
      "lng": -89.132008
    },{
      "lat": 33.755787,
      "lng": -116.359998
    },{
      "lat": 33.844843,
      "lng": -116.54911
    },{
      "lat": 44.92057,
      "lng": -93.44786
    },{
      "lat": 44.240309,
      "lng": -91.493619
    },{
      "lat": 44.968041,
      "lng": -94.419696
    },{
      "lat": 44.333304,
      "lng": -89.132027
    },{
      "lat": 33.755783,
      "lng": -116.360066
    },{
      "lat": 33.844847,
      "lng": -116.549069
    },
  ];
  double totalDistance = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++){
    totalDistance += calculateDistance(data[i]["lat"], data[i]["lng"], data[i+1]["lat"], data[i+1]["lng"]);
  }
  print(totalDistance);
}
```

Comment: As I have up to 100 points in my list would I have to do this between each point and then add up?

Comment: I have made an attempt but for some reason it doesn't return total distance. Any ideas?

Comment: Haha no. Can you provide example of your latitude longitude list ?

Comment: @Yonkee I added random dummy data.

Comment: Thanks for that. I also managed to get mine working too. Looks like i was going out of bounds on the for loop but it didn't error. By the way is this for KM or Miles? Im on Metric

Comment: Thanks for your help..I really appreciate.it. now you can go back to sleep.

Comment: Lol it was a pleasure. I sleep between 8pm-12am lol, now it's time to code.

Comment: @westdabestdb what is the return value? is it KM / meter or ?

Comment: @Yonkee what is the return value? is it KM / meter or ?

Comment: Return value is in KM

Comment: @SuriyanSuresh How would this be done in meters?

Comment: var distanceInMeters = 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
return distanceInMeters * 1000; // distance in meters

Comment: is this the Haversine method ?

Comment: I tried this code, but this code is not accurate. I used this library https://pub.dev/packages/haversine_distance instead.

Answer (score 15):

I used `westdabestdb`'s answer. It's okay.

And also, you can use `geolocator` plugin for that.

```
Geolocator.distanceBetween(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
```

[geolocator doc](https://pub.dev/documentation/geolocator/latest/)

or you can use this way [without using plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69437789/8822337)

Comment: The Geolocator plugin throws error on android. Seems this is specific to android platform

Comment: @MehulPamale try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69437789/8822337

Answer (score 12):

Use the library [latlong](https://pub.dev/packages/latlong) for common latitude and longitude calculation.
This supports both, the "Haversine" and the "Vincenty" algorithm.

```
List<dynamic> data = [
    {
        "lat": 44.968046,
        "lng": -94.420307
    },
    ...
];


final Distance distance = Distance();
double totalDistanceInM = 0;
double totalDistanceInKm = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++){
    totalDistanceInM += distance(
        LatLng(data[i]["lat"], data[i]["lng"]),
        LatLng(data[i+1]["lat"], data[i+1]["lng"])
    );

    totalDistanceInKm += distance.as(
        LengthUnit.Kilometer, 
        LatLng(data[i]["lat"], data[i]["lng"]), 
        LatLng(data[i+1]["lat"], data[i+1]["lng"]),
    );
}
```

**Update**:

Use instead [latlong2](https://pub.dev/packages/latlong2) that introduce null safety as @Mehul Pamale said in the comments.

Comment: This plugin does not support null safety

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/latlong2 found the null safe version.

Answer (score 1):

This function calculates the distance between two points (given the latitude/longitude of those points).

```
unit = the unit you desire for results              
      where: 'M' is statute miles (default) 
             'K' is kilometers            
             'N' is nautical miles
String distance(
          double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, String unit) {
         double theta = lon1 - lon2;
         double dist = sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * sin(deg2rad(lat2)) +
         cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * cos(deg2rad(theta));
         dist = acos(dist);
         dist = rad2deg(dist);
         dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
          if (unit == 'K') {
            dist = dist * 1.609344;
          } else if (unit == 'N') {
            dist = dist * 0.8684;
          }
          return dist.toStringAsFixed(2);
        }

    double deg2rad(double deg) {
      return (deg * pi / 180.0);
    }

    double rad2deg(double rad) {
      return (rad * 180.0 / pi);
    }

    void main() {
      print("Distance : " + distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, 'K'));
    }
```

Comment: Please format the code in your question correctly. *[Editing Help- Code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Answer (score 1):

I've used the `vector_math` for converting degree to radians and also the `geolocator` for getting the current user latitude and longitude if in case searching from the current location also there is a method where in you can calculate the distance between two locations directly as **Geolocator.distanceBetween(startLatitude, startLongitude, endLatitude, endLongitude)**.

```
import 'dart:math' show sin, cos, sqrt, atan2;
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

Position _currentPosition;
double earthRadius = 6371000; 

//Using pLat and pLng as dummy location
double pLat = 22.8965265;   double pLng = 76.2545445; 


//Use Geolocator to find the current location(latitude & longitude)
getUserLocation() async {
   _currentPosition = await GeoLocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
}

//Calculating the distance between two points without Geolocator plugin
getDistance(){
   var dLat = radians(pLat - _currentPosition.latitude);
   var dLng = radians(pLng - _currentPosition.longitude);
   var a = sin(dLat/2) * sin(dLat/2) + cos(radians(_currentPosition.latitude)) 
           * cos(radians(pLat)) * sin(dLng/2) * sin(dLng/2);
   var c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));
   var d = earthRadius * c;
   print(d); //d is the distance in meters
}

//Calculating the distance between two points with Geolocator plugin
getDistance(){
   final double distance = Geolocator.distanceBetween(pLat, pLng, 
           _currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude); 
   print(distance);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Geolocator.distanceBetween(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
2. print("distance: ${(distance / 1000).toStringAsFixed(0)} KM");

Answer (score 0):

**You can calculate distance by using this function and pass the latlon from and to destinations it will return the required distance**

import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:math';

```
class DistanceService{
  static double findDistance(LatLng from, LatLng to){
    var lat1 = toRadian(from.latitude);
    var lng1 = toRadian(from.longitude);
    var lat2 = toRadian(to.latitude);
    var lng2 = toRadian(to.longitude);
    
    // Haversine Formula
    var dlong = lng2 - lng1;
    var dlat = lat2 - lat1;

    var res = pow(sin((dlat / 2)), 2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * pow(sin(dlong / 2), 2);
    res = 2 * asin(sqrt(res));
    double R = 6371;
    res = res * R;
    return res;
  }

  static double toRadian(double val){
    double one_deg = (pi) / 180;
    return (one_deg * val);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Total distance calculation from LatLng without any library in FlutterMap

```
double calculateDistance(LatLng start, LatLng end) {
    var p = 0.017453292519943295;
    var a = 0.5 -
        cos((end.latitude - start.latitude) * p) / 2 +
        cos(start.latitude * p) *
            cos(end.latitude * p) *
            (1 - cos((end.longitude - start.longitude) * p)) /
            2;
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
add  geolocator: ^7.1.1 in pubyml


//get current lat and long

  var currentLocation = myLocation;
    dynamic coordinates =
        new Coordinates(myLocation.latitude, myLocation.longitude);

 //getting in meter distance

//Latitude2 and Longitude2 can get anywhere to measure the distance

double distanceInMeters = Geolocator.distanceBetween(Latitude1, Longitude1, Latitude2, Longitude2);
```