# Measure distance between two locations

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to fetch the distance between two locations in Flutter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138750/total-distance-calculation-from-latlng-list

Answer (score 5):

You can find the distance by the HaverSine formula, implemented in dart as:

```
import'dart:math' as Math;
void main()=>print(getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(73.4545,73.4545,83.5454,83.5454));



double getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

double deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.pi/180);
}
```

Output:

```
1139.9231530436646
```

[Source in Javscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula) and credits to Chuck.

Comment: @Jessica Take R to be 6371000 for meters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) plugin if you are looking for the shortest distance between two locations aka LatLng.

```
double distanceInMeters = 
  await Geolocator().distanceBetween(52.2165157, 6.9437819, 52.3546274, 4.8285838);
```

Comment: I alerady used this package but now I used this package flutter_background_geolocation I want to know is there is any methods do this job due to I wont use 1 package instead  2

Comment: Sorry there is no way of doing it using `flutter_background_geolocation` plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the `vector_math` for converting degree to radians and also the `geolocator` for getting the current user latitude and longitude if in case searching from the current location also there is a method where in you can calculate the distance between two locations directly as **Geolocator.distanceBetween(startLatitude, startLongitude, endLatitude, endLongitude)**.

```
import 'dart:math' show sin, cos, sqrt, atan2;
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

Position _currentPosition;
double earthRadius = 6371000; 

//Using pLat and pLng as dummy location
double pLat = 22.8965265;   double pLng = 76.2545445; 


//Use Geolocator to find the current location(latitude & longitude)
getUserLocation() async {
   _currentPosition = await GeoLocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
}

//Calculating the distance between two points without Geolocator plugin
getDistance(){
   var dLat = radians(pLat - _currentPosition.latitude);
   var dLng = radians(pLng - _currentPosition.longitude);
   var a = sin(dLat/2) * sin(dLat/2) + cos(radians(_currentPosition.latitude)) 
           * cos(radians(pLat)) * sin(dLng/2) * sin(dLng/2);
   var c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));
   var d = earthRadius * c;
   print(d); //d is the distance in meters
}

//Calculating the distance between two points with Geolocator plugin
getDistance(){
   final double distance = Geolocator.distanceBetween(pLat, pLng, 
           _currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude); 
   print(distance); //distance in meters
}
```