# how to calculate distance between two location on Flutter?(result should be meters)

Tags: flutter, dart

How to calculate distance between two location in dart?

Comment: Well, if that works and it is returning the distance in kilometers, then simply multiply by 1000 and you'll get the distance in meters.

`return 1000 * 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Without using plugin

```
  double calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2){
    var p = 0.017453292519943295;
    var c = cos;
    var a = 0.5 - c((lat2 - lat1) * p)/2 +
        c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) *
            (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p))/2;
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
  }
```

result is **KM**. if you want **meter** just multiply by **1000**. `return 1000 * 12742 * asin(sqrt(a))`

Comment: I used your answer but i dont know why the result is not getting right. Like I used 
```LatLng(19.975100, 73.772400) and LatLng(20.354740, 74.000488)``` this two which actual distance is hardly 1 km but by using this method i get  ```16.036513885057946``` can you please me

Answer (score 13):

You can use geolocator plugin to calculate to distances between two coordinates:

An Example:

```
var _distanceInMeters = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(
   _latitudeForCalculation,
   _longitudeForCalculation,
   _currentPosition.latitude,
   _currentPosition.longitude,
);
```

Check out [GeoLocator Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages?q=geolocator) for more info.

Comment: Yes this perfectly works fine and response is in meters.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [latlong](https://pub.dev/packages/latlong). It's a package dedicated to work with coordinates and features sophisticated calculations.

Unlike packages like [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) it does not come with integrated location services and can be used alongside packages specialized for that.

Comment: thanks for the answer but just want to mention latlong package is DEPRECATED

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check distance between only 2 coordinates, you should use Geolocator().distanceBetween, it is simple, but if you have a list of coordinates maybe you don't want use request for every item, in this case you can use this code to optimize performance:

```
double calculateDistance(LatLng start, LatLng end) {

  const double earthRadius = 6371.0; // Radius of the Earth in kilometers

  // Convert coordinates to radians
  final double lat1 = start.latitude * (pi / 180.0);
  final double lon1 = start.longitude * (pi / 180.0);
  final double lat2 = end.latitude * (pi / 180.0);
  final double lon2 = end.longitude * (pi / 180.0);

  // Calculate the differences between the coordinates
  final double dLat = lat2 - lat1;
  final double dLon = lon2 - lon1;

  // Apply the Haversine formula
  final double a = sin(dLat / 2) * sin(dLat / 2) +
      cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dLon / 2) * sin(dLon / 2);
  final double c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a));
  final double distance = earthRadius * c;

  return distance; // Distance in kilometers, add "*1000" to get meters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [latlong2](https://pub.dev/packages/latlong2) which is the continuation of [latlong](https://pub.dev/packages/latlong). It has features like distance calculation and path drawing. So you can get distance as path distance as well as direct distance.

Comment: This is a useful addition but should be a full answer and not a comment directed towards another answer. Consider expanding it into a full answer. Once you earn enough reputation you will be able to comment on or even edit others' answers.