# LateInitializationError: Field 'mapController' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, google-maps, initialization, initializer

I am trying to integrate google map in my app and giving it source and destination to place markers. It was running correctly from last few days, no error at all. Suddenly today this error shows up and map is not working. Even though it is not showing google map on the screen just the blank white screen.

```
class MapView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapViewState createState() => _MapViewState();
}

class _MapViewState extends State<MapView> {
  CameraPosition _initialLocation = CameraPosition(target: LatLng(0.0, 0.0));
  **late GoogleMapController mapController ;**

  late Position _currentPosition;
  String _currentAddress = '';

  final startAddressController = TextEditingController();
  final destinationAddressController = TextEditingController();

  final startAddressFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final destinationAddressFocusNode = FocusNode();

  String _startAddress = '';
  String _destinationAddress = '';
  double? _placeDistance;

  Set<Marker> markers = {};

  late PolylinePoints polylinePoints;
  List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];
  Map<PolylineId, Polyline> polylines = {};

  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  Widget _textField({

    required TextEditingController controller,
    required FocusNode focusNode,
    required String label,
    required String hint,
    required double width,
    required Icon prefixIcon,
    Widget? suffixIcon,
    required Function(String) locationCallback,

  }) {
    return Container(

      width: width * 0.8,
      child: TextField(
        onChanged: (value) {
          locationCallback(value);
        },
        controller: controller,
        focusNode: focusNode,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: prefixIcon,
          suffixIcon: suffixIcon,
          labelText: label,
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.grey.shade400,
              width: 2,
            ),
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.blue.shade300,
              width: 2,
            ),
          ),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          hintText: hint,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Method for retrieving the current location
  _getCurrentLocation() async {
    await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
        .then((Position position) async {
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = position;
        print('CURRENT POS: $_currentPosition');
        **mapController.animateCamera(**
          CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
            CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
              zoom: 18.0,
            ),
          ),
        );
      });
      await _getAddress();
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
```

Next part:

```
_getAddress() async {
    try {
      List<Placemark> p = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
          _currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude);

      Placemark place = p[0];

      setState(() {
        _currentAddress =
        "${place.name}, ${place.locality}, ${place.postalCode}, ${place.country}";
        startAddressController.text = _currentAddress;
        _startAddress = _currentAddress;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  // Method for calculating the distance between two places
  Future<bool> _calculateDistance() async {
    try {
      // Retrieving placemarks from addresses
      List<Location> startPlacemark = await locationFromAddress(_startAddress);
      List<Location> destinationPlacemark =
      await locationFromAddress(_destinationAddress);

      // Use the retrieved coordinates of the current position,
      // instead of the address if the start position is user's
      // current position, as it results in better accuracy.
      double startLatitude = _startAddress == _currentAddress
          ? _currentPosition.latitude
          : startPlacemark[0].latitude;

      double startLongitude = _startAddress == _currentAddress
          ? _currentPosition.longitude
          : startPlacemark[0].longitude;

      double destinationLatitude = destinationPlacemark[0].latitude;
      double destinationLongitude = destinationPlacemark[0].longitude;

      String startCoordinatesString = '($startLatitude, $startLongitude)';
      String destinationCoordinatesString =
          '($destinationLatitude, $destinationLongitude)';

      // Start Location Marker
      Marker startMarker = Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(startCoordinatesString),
        position: LatLng(startLatitude, startLongitude),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: 'Start $startCoordinatesString',
          snippet: _startAddress,
        ),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
      );

      // Destination Location Marker
      Marker destinationMarker = Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(destinationCoordinatesString),
        position: LatLng(destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: 'Destination $destinationCoordinatesString',
          snippet: _destinationAddress,
        ),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
      );


      // Adding the markers to the list
      markers.add(startMarker);
      markers.add(destinationMarker);

      print(
        'START COORDINATES: ($startLatitude, $startLongitude)',
      );
      print(
        'DESTINATION COORDINATES: ($destinationLatitude, $destinationLongitude)',
      );

      // Calculating to check that the position relative
      // to the frame, and pan & zoom the camera accordingly.
      double miny = (startLatitude <= destinationLatitude)
          ? startLatitude
          : destinationLatitude;
      double minx = (startLongitude <= destinationLongitude)
          ? startLongitude
          : destinationLongitude;
      double maxy = (startLatitude <= destinationLatitude)
          ? destinationLatitude
          : startLatitude;
      double maxx = (startLongitude <= destinationLongitude)
          ? destinationLongitude
          : startLongitude;

      double southWestLatitude = miny;
      double southWestLongitude = minx;

      double northEastLatitude = maxy;
      double northEastLongitude = maxx;

      // Accommodate the two locations within the
      // camera view of the map
      mapController.animateCamera(
        CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(
          LatLngBounds(
            northeast: LatLng(northEastLatitude, northEastLongitude),
            southwest: LatLng(southWestLatitude, southWestLongitude),
          ),
          100.0,
        ),
      );

      // Calculating the distance between the start and the end positions
      // with a straight path, without considering any route
      // double distanceInMeters = await Geolocator.bearingBetween(
      //   startLatitude,
      //   startLongitude,
      //   destinationLatitude,
      //   destinationLongitude,
      // );

      await _createPolylines(startLatitude, startLongitude, destinationLatitude,
          destinationLongitude);

      double totalDistance = 0.0;

      // Calculating the total distance by adding the distance
      // between small segments
      for (int i = 0; i < polylineCoordinates.length - 1; i++) {
        totalDistance += _coordinateDistance(

          polylineCoordinates[i].latitude,
          polylineCoordinates[i].longitude,
          polylineCoordinates[i + 1].latitude,
          polylineCoordinates[i + 1].longitude,

        );
      }

      setState(() {
        _placeDistance = totalDistance;
        print('DISTANCE: $_placeDistance km');
      });

      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return false;
  }



  // Formula for calculating distance between two coordinates
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/54138876/11910277
  double _coordinateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    var p = 0.017453292519943295;
    var c = cos;
    var a = 0.5 -
        c((lat2 - lat1) * p) / 2 +
        c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) * (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p)) / 2;
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
  }

  // Create the polylines for showing the route between two places
  _createPolylines(

      double startLatitude,
      double startLongitude,
      double destinationLatitude,
      double destinationLongitude,
      ) async {


    polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();
    PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
      Secrets.API_KEY, // Google Maps API Key
      PointLatLng(startLatitude, startLongitude),
      PointLatLng(destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude),
      travelMode: TravelMode.driving,

    );

      result.points.forEach((PointLatLng point) {
        polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));

        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text(
                'Poly here'),
          ),
        );
      });




    PolylineId id = PolylineId('poly');
    Polyline polyline = Polyline(
      polylineId: id,
      color: Colors.red,
      points: polylineCoordinates,
      width: 3,
    );
    polylines[id] = polyline;
    setState(() {});
  }

 

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getCurrentLocation();
    _calculateDistance();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    mapController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
      height: height,
      width: width,
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            // Map View
            GoogleMap(
              markers: Set<Marker>.from(markers),
              initialCameraPosition: _initialLocation,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
              zoomControlsEnabled: false,
              polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(polylines.values),
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                setState(() {
                  mapCreated = true;
                });

               mapController = controller;
              },
            ),
            // Show zoom buttons
            SafeArea(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ClipOval(
                      child: Material(
                        color: Colors.blue.shade100, // button color
                        child: InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.blue, // inkwell color
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 50,
                            height: 50,
                            child: Icon(Icons.add),
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            mapController.animateCamera(
                              CameraUpdate.zoomIn(),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: try GoogleMapController mapController = GoogleMapController();

Comment: @ShailandraRajput No, It didn't worked.

Comment: You have to Initialise mapController. you can Initialise in initstate.

Comment: Where are you initializing `mapController`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh just below the Camera Position on 3rd line within **

Comment: @ShailandraRajput Can U tell me how could I initialize it in initstate?

Comment: Cant find the line, it could be like `GoogleMapController mapController = GoogleMapController();` as mentioned above , while this is not working, can you include where you are doing `mapController = .....`?

Comment: By doing GoogleMapController mapController = GoogleMapController(); it shows error box that says : "The class 'GoogleMapController' doesn't have a default constructor.  Try using one of the named constructors defined in 'GoogleMapController'." @YeasinSheikh

Comment: From the doc I find it use `Completer<GoogleMapController>` then get `GoogleMapController` from future.

Comment: I have tried this it shows error in further code in : mapController.animateCamera( .....   It shows: error: The method 'animateCamera' isn't defined for the type 'Completer'. (undefined_method at [flash_chat] lib\screens\Map_Screen.dart:398) @YeasinSheikh

Comment: Are you using [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter)

Comment: Yes, its already added @YeasinSheikh

Comment: This problem occured today while I am using it from weeks

Comment: Not sure how you are initializing the `mapController` not able to find on your snippet, do a recheck , you can also make it nullable and check null value

Comment: @YeasinSheikhlate GoogleMapController mapController ; I am initializing it like this in my snippet. And when I assign it as null : GoogleMapController mapController = null. It shows the following error "A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'GoogleMapController'. "

Answer (score 8):

You have to store the `GoogleMapController` when you create the `GoogleMap` widget like this:

```
GoogleMap(
  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
    // here save the value
    mapController = controller;
  }
```

You have to make sure that this `onMapCreated` runs before you try to access your `mapController` (using a `FutureBuilder` for example), otherwise you will keep getting this error message. The other option is to remove `late` keyword, allow the member to be null, and check for null value before using.

Also, don't forget to properly dispose the controller:

```
@override
void dispose() {
  mapController.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

In your code, you call `_getCurrentLocation` `async` function from `initState`. It is generally not a good approach, because `initState` can't be an `async` function, so there is no way to use `await` to make sure these functions are completed before your widget is built for the first time.

But in this case the biggest problem is that you will have a valid `GoogleMapController` only after `GoogleMap` widget is created. That's what `onMapCreated` is primarily meant for, to get the `GoogleMapController` after the map is created.

And since in `_getCurrentLocation` you try to access `mapController`, it will not be available yet, because it will likely be executed before the `GoogleMap` is created.

Now, `_getCurrentLocation` uses `await` to get current position, and once this is completed, it tries to call `mapController.animateCamera`. Here is the reason why you could experience earlier that it works. This is a typical racing problem. If `Geolocator.getCurrentPosition` takes enough time, it can happen that `GoogleMap` is already built, therefore you have a valid `GoogleMapController`. But you can't be sure, as your current error shows, it depends on how long getting current position takes.

What is the solution? You have to reorganise your code so that you use `mapController` only after `GoogleMap` is created. For example move your `_getCurrentLocation` function call from `initState` to `onMapCreated`, this way you can be sure that you have a valid map controller. But make sure that no code relies on `mapController` before it is available.

Here is some code showing how can you get this work:

```
class MyPageHomeMap extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyPageHomeMap({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyPageHomeMap> createState() => _MyPageHomeMapState();
}

class _MyPageHomeMapState extends State<MyPageHomeMap> {

  bool _mapCreated = false;
  late GoogleMapController mapController;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
              children: [
                GoogleMap(           
                    initialCameraPosition: <something>,
                    onMapCreated: _onMapCreated),
                if (!_mapCreated) const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
              ],
            ),
    );
  }

  _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
    setState(() {
      _mapCreated = true;
    });
    // get current position here and use mapController when it is completed
  }
}
```

Comment: How could I check that onMapCreated runs before accessed? Could you help with the code? Plus I have checked with disposing it and storing GoogleMapController didn't worked.

Comment: For example create a member in the state class like ‘mapCreated=false;’, set it to true in ‘onMapCreated’ using ‘setState’, and display a progress indicator while map is beeing created.

Comment: Didn't worked same error

Comment: Update your question with current code, including creation of `GoogleMap` widget, so that I can have a look at it.

Comment: I have edited question and posted the next half of the code. I guess now you may figure it out.

Comment: I will add my points to the answer shortly.

Comment: @UsamaBinTahir I added to the answer.

Comment: Sir, I appreciate your concern towards me but it still shows the same error and progress indicator keeps on rolling but doesn't show map.

Comment: Okay, so please update you current entire code so that I can have a look. You can also post a new question and copy the link here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70776246/lateinitializationerror-field-mapcontroller-has-not-been-initialized-when-i-t

Comment: Entire code is posted there.