# The method 'toDouble' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: toDouble()

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-maps, location

I am trying to make a tracking app which calculates the distance between two coordinates
But this is what it is showing in the terminal.I think it is a very common problem but don,t know how to solve this.

Everytime I run it it shows this error

Here the _currentposition variable is not getting initialised due to late intialization error

**DEBUG**

```
    The method 'toDouble' was called on null.
    Receiver: null
    Tried calling: toDouble()
    
    When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
    #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:68:5)
    #1      _MapViewState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:google_track/main.dart:555:62)
    #2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:989:21)
    #3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:198:24)
    #4      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:608:11)
    #5      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
    #6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:230:7)
    #7      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:563:9)
    #8      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:94:12)
    #9      PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:139:9)
    #10     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:539:8)
    #11     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:137:18)
    #12     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:123:7)
    #13     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:439:19)
    #14     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:419:22)
    #15     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:322:11)
    #16     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
    #17     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
    #18     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
    #19     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
    #23     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:169:10)
    #24     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:293:7)
    #25     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:88:31)
    (elided 3 frames from dart:async)
    Handler: "onTap"
    Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#c6efd
      debugOwner: GestureDetector
      state: possible
      won arena
      finalPosition: Offset(357.8, 790.9)
      finalLocalPosition: Offset(31.1, 53.3)
      button: 1
      sent tap down
    ====================================================================================================
    I have wrote the code like this,but it is still showing the error

// This is the code which is showing the error

**CODE**

    import 'dart:core';
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_polyline_points/flutter_polyline_points.dart';
    import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
    import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
    import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
    
    import 'dart:math' show cos, sqrt, asin;
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
     class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Maps',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: MapView(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MapView extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MapViewState createState() => _MapViewState();
    }
    
    class _MapViewState extends State<MapView> {
      CameraPosition _initialLocation = CameraPosition(target: LatLng(0.0, 0.0));
      late GoogleMapController mapController;
    
         Position? _currentPosition;
      String _currentAddress = '';
    
      final startAddressController = TextEditingController();
      final destinationAddressController = TextEditingController();
    
      final startAddressFocusNode = FocusNode();
      final desrinationAddressFocusNode = FocusNode();
    
      String _startAddress = '';
      String _destinationAddress = '';
      String? _placeDistance;
    
      Set<Marker> markers = {};
    
      late PolylinePoints polylinePoints;
      Map<PolylineId, Polyline> polylines = {};
      List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];
    
      final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    
      var latitude;
      var longitude;
      @override
      Widget _textField({
        required TextEditingController controller,
        required FocusNode focusNode,
        required String label,
        required String hint,
        required double width,
        required Icon prefixIcon,
        Widget? suffixIcon,
        required Function(String) locationCallback,
      }) {
        return Container(
          width: width * 0.8,
          child: TextField(
            onChanged: (value) {
              locationCallback(value);
            },
            controller: controller,
            focusNode: focusNode,
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: prefixIcon,
              suffixIcon: suffixIcon,
              labelText: label,
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                  width: 2,
                ),
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.blue.shade300,
                  width: 2,
                ),
              ),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              hintText: hint,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      // Method for retrieving the current location
      _getCurrentLocation() async {
        await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
            .then((Position position) async {
          setState(() {
            _currentPosition = position;
            print('CURRENT POS: $_currentPosition');
            mapController.animateCamera(
              CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                CameraPosition(
                  target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
                  zoom: 18.0,
                ),
              ),
            );
          });
          await _getAddress();
        }).catchError((e) {
          print(e);
        });
      }
    
      // Method for retrieving the address
      _getAddress() async {
        try {
          List<Placemark> p = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
              _currentPosition??latitude.toDouble(), _currentPosition??longitude.toDouble());
    
          Placemark place = p[0];
    
          setState(() {
            _currentAddress =
            "${place.name}, ${place.locality}, ${place.postalCode}, ${place.country}";
            startAddressController.text = _currentAddress;
            _startAddress = _currentAddress;
          });
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      }
    
      // Method for calculating the distance between two places
      Future<bool> _calculateDistance() async {
        try {
          // Retrieving placemarks from addresses
          List<Location> startPlacemark = await locationFromAddress(_startAddress);
          List<Location> destinationPlacemark =
          await locationFromAddress(_destinationAddress);
    
          // Use the retrieved coordinates of the current position,
          // instead of the address if the start position is user's
          // current position, as it results in better accuracy.
          double startLatitude = _startAddress == _currentAddress
              ? _currentPosition??latitude.toDouble()
              : startPlacemark[0].latitude;
    
          double startLongitude = _startAddress == _currentAddress
              ? _currentPosition??longitude.toDouble()
              : startPlacemark[0].longitude;
    
          double destinationLatitude = destinationPlacemark[0].latitude;
          double destinationLongitude = destinationPlacemark[0].longitude;
    
          String startCoordinatesString = '($startLatitude, $startLongitude)';
          String destinationCoordinatesString =
              '($destinationLatitude, $destinationLongitude)';
    
          // Start Location Marker
          Marker startMarker = Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId(startCoordinatesString),
            position: LatLng(startLatitude, startLongitude),
            infoWindow: InfoWindow(
              title: 'Start $startCoordinatesString',
              snippet: _startAddress,
            ),
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
          );
    
          // Destination Location Marker
          Marker destinationMarker = Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId(destinationCoordinatesString),
            position: LatLng(destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude),
            infoWindow: InfoWindow(
              title: 'Destination $destinationCoordinatesString',
              snippet: _destinationAddress,
            ),
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
          );
    
          // Adding the markers to the list
          markers.add(startMarker);
          markers.add(destinationMarker);
    
          print(
            'START COORDINATES: ($startLatitude, $startLongitude)',
          );
          print(
            'DESTINATION COORDINATES: ($destinationLatitude, $destinationLongitude)',
          );
    
          // Calculating to check that the position relative
          // to the frame, and pan & zoom the camera accordingly.
          double miny = (startLatitude <= destinationLatitude)
              ? startLatitude
              : destinationLatitude;
          double minx = (startLongitude <= destinationLongitude)
              ? startLongitude
              : destinationLongitude;
          double maxy = (startLatitude <= destinationLatitude)
              ? destinationLatitude
              : startLatitude;
          double maxx = (startLongitude <= destinationLongitude)
              ? destinationLongitude
              : startLongitude;
    
          double southWestLatitude = miny;
          double southWestLongitude = minx;
    
          double northEastLatitude = maxy;
          double northEastLongitude = maxx;
    
          // Accommodate the two locations within the
          // camera view of the map
          mapController.animateCamera(
            CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(
              LatLngBounds(
                northeast: LatLng(northEastLatitude, northEastLongitude),
                southwest: LatLng(southWestLatitude, southWestLongitude),
              ),
              100.0,
            ),
          );
    
          // Calculating the distance between the start and the end positions
          // with a straight path, without considering any route
          // double distanceInMeters = await Geolocator.bearingBetween(
          //   startLatitude,
          //   startLongitude,
          //   destinationLatitude,
          //   destinationLongitude,
          // );
    
          await _createPolylines(startLatitude, startLongitude, destinationLatitude,
              destinationLongitude);
    
          double totalDistance = 0.0;
    
          // Calculating the total distance by adding the distance
          // between small segments
          for (int i = 0; i < polylineCoordinates.length - 1; i++) {
            totalDistance += _coordinateDistance(
              polylineCoordinates[i].latitude,
              polylineCoordinates[i].longitude,
              polylineCoordinates[i + 1].latitude,
              polylineCoordinates[i + 1].longitude,
            );
          }
    
          setState(() {
            _placeDistance = totalDistance.toStringAsFixed(2);
            print('DISTANCE: $_placeDistance km');
          });
    
          return true;
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
        return false;
      }
    
      // Formula for calculating distance between two coordinates
      // https://stackoverflow.com/a/54138876/11910277
      double _coordinateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
        var p = 0.017453292519943295;
        var c = cos;
        var a = 0.5 -
            c((lat2 - lat1) * p) / 2 +
            c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) * (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p)) / 2;
        return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
      }
    
      // Create the polylines for showing the route between two places
      _createPolylines(
          double startLatitude,
          double startLongitude,
          double destinationLatitude,
          double destinationLongitude,
          ) async {
        polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();
        PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
          "YOUR_API_KEY", // Google Maps API Key
          PointLatLng(startLatitude, startLongitude),
          PointLatLng(destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude),
          travelMode: TravelMode.transit,
        );
    
        if (result.points.isNotEmpty) {
          result.points.forEach((PointLatLng point) {
            polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
          });
        }
    
        PolylineId id = PolylineId('poly');
        Polyline polyline = Polyline(
          polylineId: id,
          color: Colors.red,
          points: polylineCoordinates,
          width: 3,
        );
        polylines[id] = polyline;
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _getCurrentLocation();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        return Container(
          height: height,
          width: width,
          child: Scaffold(
            key: _scaffoldKey,
            body: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                // Map View
                GoogleMap(
                  markers: Set<Marker>.from(markers),
                  initialCameraPosition: _initialLocation,
                  myLocationEnabled: true,
                  myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                  zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                  polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(polylines.values),
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                    mapController = controller;
                  },
                ),
                // Show zoom buttons
                SafeArea(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ClipOval(
                          child: Material(
                            color: Colors.blue.shade100, // button color
                            child: InkWell(
                              splashColor: Colors.blue, // inkwell color
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: 50,
                                height: 50,
                                child: Icon(Icons.add),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {
                                mapController.animateCamera(
                                  CameraUpdate.zoomIn(),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        ClipOval(
                          child: Material(
                            color: Colors.blue.shade100, // button color
                            child: InkWell(
                              splashColor: Colors.blue, // inkwell color
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: 50,
                                height: 50,
                                child: Icon(Icons.remove),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {
                                mapController.animateCamera(
                                  CameraUpdate.zoomOut(),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SafeArea(
                  child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20,bottom: 10.0),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white70,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)
                        ),
                      ),
                      width: width*0.9,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children:<Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "Places",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0
                              ),
                              
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            _textField(
                              label: "Start",
                              hint: "Choose the destination point",
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.looks_one),
                              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.my_location),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  startAddressController.text=_currentAddress;
                                  _startAddress=_currentAddress;
                                },
                              ),
                              controller:startAddressController,
                              focusNode: startAddressFocusNode,
                              width:width,
                              locationCallback: (String value){
                                setState(() {
                                  _startAddress=value;
                                });
                              }),
    
                            SizedBox(height:10),
                            _textField(
                                label: 'Destination',
                                hint: 'Choose destination',
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.looks_two),
                                controller: destinationAddressController,
                                focusNode: desrinationAddressFocusNode,
                                width: width,
                                locationCallback: (String value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _destinationAddress = value;
                                  });
                                }),
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Visibility(
                              visible: _placeDistance == null ? false : true,
                              child: Text(
                                'DISTANCE: $_placeDistance km',
                                style:TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 5),
                            ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: (_startAddress != '' &&
                                  _destinationAddress != '')
                                  ? () async {
                                startAddressFocusNode.unfocus();
                                desrinationAddressFocusNode.unfocus();
                                setState(() {
                                  if (markers.isNotEmpty) markers.clear();
                                  if (polylines.isNotEmpty)
                                    polylines.clear();
                                  if (polylineCoordinates.isNotEmpty)
                                    polylineCoordinates.clear();
                                  _placeDistance = null;
                                });
    
                                _calculateDistance().then((isCalculated) {
                                  if (isCalculated) {
                                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                        .showSnackBar(
                                      SnackBar(
                                        content: Text(
                                            'Distance Calculated Sucessfully'),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  } else {
                                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                        .showSnackBar(
                                      SnackBar(
                                        content: Text(
                                            'Error Calculating Distance'),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }
                                });
                              }
                               :null,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  'Show Route'.toUpperCase(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                primary: Colors.red,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                            ]
                        ),
    
                      ),
                    ),
    
    
    
                  ),
                ),
                ),
                // Show current location button
                SafeArea(
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
                      child: ClipOval(
                        child: Material(
                          color: Colors.orange.shade100, // button color
                          child: InkWell(
                            splashColor: Colors.orange, // inkwell color
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: 56,
                              height: 56,
                              child: Icon(Icons.my_location),
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              mapController.animateCamera(
                                CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                                  CameraPosition(
                                    target: LatLng(
                                      _currentPosition??latitude.toDouble(),
                                      _currentPosition??longitude.toDouble(),
                                    ),
                                    zoom: 18.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
           ),
        ],
        ),
        ),
        );
      }
    }

    >give me a help guys
```

Comment: Make sure that your latitude and longitude or position is not null

Comment: Have you checked it using `print()`?

Comment: You didn't set values for `longitude` and `latitude` anywhere, can you try setting?

Comment: can u tell me how to set the values of latitude and longitude as I am trying to set it but I am getting the error

Answer (score 0):

You call

```
await placemarkFromCoordinates(
  _currentPosition??latitude.toDouble(),
  _currentPosition??longitude.toDouble()
);
```

Since you're using the ?? operator, that means use _*currentPosition* when it is not null, otherwise, use latitude.toDouble(). But your variables

```
  var latitude;
  var longitude;
```

are never assigned, so they are always null, which leads to your error.

I think what you need is a call like that:

```
await placemarkFromCoordinates(
  _currentPosition?.latitude.toDouble() ?? defaultLatitude,   
  _currentPosition?.longitude.toDouble() ?? defaultLongitude
);
```

So if _*currentPosition* is not null, the lat/lon values of the position are passed and with the ?? operator you can specify default values if _*currentPosition* is null.